# I can't figure out how to put them on the same line

Tags: html

I want to make logo and my `navigation :ul, li` to display on the same line.

Code:

```
    <div class="main-header">
        <img class="logo" src="logo-2.png">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Feed</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Popular</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
                </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Use display:inline-block CSS on the list items.

Comment: Where is your CSS ? Without CSS, you can't do so

Comment: A quick Google search for "html navigation ul horizontal" returns this informative link: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Comment: @alexanderbird No. Please don't reference w3schools. Full of errors. Use MDN instead.

Comment: @Raptor, as a general rule I agree. But, is it so bad that we should never use it ever? Would you also say we shouldn't reference unknown blogs because many blog pages are full of errors?  I only included it here to show that a simple google search came up with some suggestions, and from a quick skim read it looked mostly correct. Could you suggest an MDN alternative to the w3schools page?

Comment: w3schools lacks update & maintenance, and it does not provide up-to-date information, that's why I don't recommend it. MDN updates frequently according to the standards accurately. Looking up MDN for CSS definitions is what I recommend. Since MDN is not a tutorial site, it does not provide exact tutorial like w3schools does. Instead, you can look into sites like CSS Tricks, Tut Plus, etc, which they provide accurate tutorials. An equivalent tutorial page can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/targetting-menu-elements-submenus-navigation-bar/)

Comment: By the way, [Move the Web Forward](http://movethewebforward.org/) campaign might be useful for web development learners.

Comment: For posterity: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```css
li{display: inline-block}
ul{float: left;}
img{float: left;}
```

```html
 <body class="homepage">
    <div class="header header-size single-header">

    <div class="main-header">
        <img class="logo" src="logo-2.png">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Feed</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Popular</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
                </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: `display: inline-block` is better, as it has **width**. Natural inline elements will shrink according to its contents, which may not be suitable for a menu.